# undefined reference to 'dlopen' 'dlclose' 'dlerror' 'dlsym

Tags: installation, compiling

I'm installing a program on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I've run `./configure` and I get no error messages, when I then run `make` I get errors. Please see below for the errors:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mel/Documents/Software/plinkseq-0.09'
Making all in lib
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mel/Documents/Software/plinkseq-0.09/lib'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mel/Documents/Software/plinkseq-0.09/lib'
Making all in client
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mel/Documents/Software/plinkseq-0.09/client'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -g -O2 -lz -ldl   -o pseq pseq-skat.o pseq-util.o pseq-ibs.o pseq-main.o pseq-func.o pseq-summaries.o pseq-views.o pseq-assoc.o pseq-genic.o pseq-compare.o pseq-ibd.o pseq-loaders.o pseq-clusters.o pseq-varfunc.o pseq-glm-tests.o pseq-stepup.o pseq-kbac.o pseq-netassoc.o pseq-davies.o pseq-gseq.o pseq-extra.o pseq-cnv.o pseq-chet.o ../lib/libplinkseq.la 
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -o .libs/pseq pseq-skat.o pseq-util.o pseq-ibs.o pseq-main.o pseq-func.o pseq-summaries.o pseq-views.o pseq-assoc.o pseq-genic.o pseq-compare.o pseq-ibd.o pseq-loaders.o pseq-clusters.o pseq-varfunc.o pseq-glm-tests.o pseq-stepup.o pseq-kbac.o pseq-netassoc.o pseq-davies.o pseq-gseq.o pseq-extra.o pseq-cnv.o pseq-chet.o  -ldl ../lib/.libs/libplinkseq.so -lz -lprotobuf
../lib/.libs/libplinkseq.so: undefined reference to `dlopen'
../lib/.libs/libplinkseq.so: undefined reference to `dlclose'
../lib/.libs/libplinkseq.so: undefined reference to `dlerror'
../lib/.libs/libplinkseq.so: undefined reference to `dlsym'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [pseq] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mel/Documents/Software/plinkseq-0.09/client'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mel/Documents/Software/plinkseq-0.09'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm not too good with linux so please be simple with replies. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run configure again as `./configure LDFLAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed`, then run `make` again. It helped me compiling COIN-OR OS on Ubuntu 13.10, where I had the exact same error.

[[source of this solution](http://list.coin-or.org/pipermail/ipopt/2013-November/003570.html)]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked for me -- on an old RHEL 5 system that I'm forced to use! I'm compiling curl and Openssl from source so curl can use more "modern" TLS protocols.  :(